# XDocument C# parse node value inside node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing

I have an XML document which basically looks like this:

```
<Item>
 <Seller>
   <UserID>SomeSeller</UserID>
   <FeedbackScore>2535</FeedbackScore>
 </Seller>
</Item>
```

Now I'm trying to parse the document like following:

```
 var document = XDocument.Parse(upcList);
                    XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
                    var result= document
                        .Descendants(ns + "Item")
                        .Select(item => new CustomClass
                        {
                            FeedBackScore = Convert.ToInt32(item.Descendants(ns+ "Seller")
                                            .Where(p=>p.Name.LocalName=="FeedbackScore").FirstOrDefault()),             

                            Sales = (int) item.Element(ns+"QuantitySold"),
                            Location = (string)item.Element(ns+"Location"),
                            CurrentPrice = (double)item.Element(ns + "CurrentPrice"),
                            Title = (string)item.Element(ns + "Title"),
                            ItemID = (string)item.Element(ns + "ItemID")

                        }).ToList();
```

Please note this part how I try to parse the FeedbackScore node value:

```
   FeedBackScore = Convert.ToInt32(item.Descendants(ns+ "Seller")
                                            .Where(p=>p.Name.LocalName=="FeedbackScore").FirstOrDefault()),
```

But when I try to parse it I'm getting all "FeedbackScore" nodes values as "0" :(

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can  I fetch this value inside this node "2535"?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: Did you try with `XNamespace ns = ""` ?

Comment: @Fildor if i try that, then the other values won't be fetched xD

Comment: So, document.Descendants() returns entries, right? It's just that one that will return "0"? Am I right?

Comment: @Fildor yes that's correct, all other values that I have shown here, like ItemID, Location, Title are fetched... Only this one "FeedbackScore" im not sure how to fetch ^^

Comment: What Type does FirstOrDefault return? Isn't that an XElement? On which you should use the `Value` property?

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns 0 as I could've seen later on in the last line of code when I get a list xD

Comment: @Fildor the property "FeedbackScore" in my class  gets assigned with a value 0 :/

Comment: @Fildor And I can clearly see in every Item node that FeedbackScore isn't 0 xD

Comment: Yes, that's because of the Convert. Not sure if "null" gets converted to 0, but that's my suspicion. But if so, that would mean that your element is not found.

Comment: @Fildor Oh okay that makes sense.. I'm probably getting the null v alue for this and when converted to int32 it gets 0 value ^^

Comment: I guess by calling `Descendants(ns+ "Seller")` you will get the `Seller` Nodes and their name will never match `"FeedbackScore"` and yields `null`. Then `Convert.ToIn32(null)`yields `0`. You should look out for the "FeedBackScore" directly with `Descendants()` (something like this `item.Descendants("FeedBackValue").FirstOrDefault()` should do the trick).

Comment: @LittleBit okay gonna try that ^^

Comment: @LittleBit getting now error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'System.IConvertible"

Comment: Dont try to Convert the element, convert its value `item.Descendants("FeedBackValue").FirstOrDefault()?.Value`

Comment: @LittleBit ah that works, finally! You've saved me hours now ! Thanks a lot =)

Comment: No problem. I'll will post this as answer if somebody stumbles upon the same problem in the future and may save some more time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
FeedBackScore = Convert.ToInt32(item.Descendants(ns + "FeedbackScore").Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakenly checked the names of the `Seller` Nodes not its Children. By doing so, the `FirstOrDefault()` will yield `null`(condition of `Where()` is never met due the wrong Node) and `Convert.ToIn32(null)` will yield `0`.

To fix this, you can go for the "FeedbackScore" Node directly and Convert its Value like this

```
FeedBackScore = Convert.ToInt32(item.Descendants("FeedBackValue").FirstOrDefault()?.Value),
```

Answer (score 1):

`Descendants` here will return `Seller` elements, and then you check if any of them have the name `FeedbackScore`. This isn't possible - they can't have two names at once.

Assuming you want the `FeedbackScore` *only* if the parent is `Seller`, you need to read the `Elements` of the `Seller` elements.

I'd also note you can use the explicit conversions in the same way you do for other properties.

Putting that together, this would work:

```cs
FeedBackScore = (int) item.Elements(ns + "Seller")
    .Elements(ns + "FeedbackScore")
    .Single()
```

If this element isn't always present, you can default to `0`:

```
FeedBackScore = (int?) item.Elements(ns + "Seller")
    .Elements(ns + "FeedbackScore")
    .SingleOrDefault() ?? 0;
```